# Sublime Text display HTML syntax in Python string

Tags: python, html, sublimetext2

Using Sublime Text 2.

Trying to display HTML syntax coloring in .py files, when the HTML is in block quotes.

Example:

```
form = """
<form action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <input name="q">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
"""
```

In Sublime, the html code in the quotes are only colored as string text.

I'd like the html code to have proper syntax coloring, as in .html files.

Apologies if this has been answered, I spent a good amount of time searching for an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: To the best of my limited knowledge, it won't.  You have a string in Python, so that's what it's colored as.  This is one reason why it can be helpful to use some kind of template so that you can keep all your HTML and Python code separate, which would let you use the proper syntax highlighting in their respective files.

Comment: @coralv is correct. This is not possible in Sublime Text 2 or 3.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution, given that I know you can see SQL syntax within strings in sublime for .py files.

Thanks for the response, though!

Comment: This is possible, as seen in the `embedded` scopes of the `HTML` [**sublime-syntax**](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/master/HTML/HTML.sublime-syntax#L88-L107) file. You would have to add a custom set of sub-scopes to the `string.quoted.double.block.python` scope.